# Make a draw apps with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, events, canvas

I want to make a draw app in JS. So I've started to create a canvas in HTML and also write some codeIN JS. However, when I run my script, I can only draw some point and what I would like is to draw lines manually with the mouse.

Could you help me, please ?

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  var clear = document.getElementById("clear");
  var paint = false;

  can = document.querySelector("canvas");
  context = can.getContext("2d");
  can.addEventListener("mouseup", finish);
  can.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
  clear.addEventListener("click", clearContent);
  can.addEventListener("mousedown", painting);

  function clearContent(){ 
    context.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
  }

  function painting(){
    paint = true;
  }

  function finish(){
    paint = false;
  }

  function draw(e){
    if (!paint) return 0;
      context.strokeStyle="black";
      context.lineWidth = 5;
      context.lineCap = "round";
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
      context.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
      context.stroke();
  }
});
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<br>
<button id="clear">Clear</button>
```

Comment: I appreciate if you want to build this in vanilla JS, but otherwise something like Fabric makes this sort of thing very easy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to draw the line from the *previous* point, not the *current* point. It is quite straightforward to do that, because the canvas context remembers the previous point. Also, don't call `beginPath` as this would interrupt the sequence of points to connect.

You could also use a better way to pinpoint the exact coordinates.

See this variant of your code:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  var clear = document.getElementById("clear");
  var paint = false;

  can = document.querySelector("canvas");
  context = can.getContext("2d");
  can.addEventListener("mouseup", finish);
  can.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
  clear.addEventListener("click", clearContent);
  can.addEventListener("mousedown", painting);

  function clearContent(){ 
    context.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
  }

  function painting(){
    paint = true;
    context.beginPath(); /// <--- move this here
  }

  function finish(){
    paint = false;
  }

  function draw(e){
    if (!paint) return 0;
      var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
      var x = e.clientX - rect.left;
      var y = e.clientY - rect.top;
      context.strokeStyle="black";
      context.lineWidth = 5;
      context.lineCap = "round";
      // Don't do any of these here:
      // context.beginPath();
      // context.moveTo(x, y);
      // ... only draw line from previous point:
      context.lineTo(x, y);
      context.stroke();

  }
});
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<br>
<button id="clear">Clear</button>
```

Comment: Thank you it works I can draw lines. However, when I draw something, it doesn't leave traces exactly where I point the mouse but just below. Also, when I clear the canvas to draw something new, it saves the last draw, and when I begin the new draw, the last one appears. It doesn't make a sense.

Comment: For the first problem you would need to post the exact HTML and CSS that you are using. As you probably noticed, I had updated your question with some minimal HTML, as that was completely missing in your question. But please update it there, so what you explained here can be reproduced with it. For the second issue (Clear button): I have updated the answer (cf. the code in `painting`)

Comment: Ok, I've wriiten the same html code as yours and séparate the Css and the html code. It works correctly but the button clear doesn't work. Well I can clear the rect but when I start a new draw, the last one appears, so it doesn't really clear the canvas.